# Clear a pod's log in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

How could I clear existing log of a specific pod?

So that I can get all logs since that time with `kubectl logs` next time.

Thanks!

Comment: Do your application writes the logs to a shared volume or just printing out logs to STDOUT?

Comment: @ShahedMehbub Just to STDOUT.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't, the log rotation is generally implemented in Docker (or sometimes via logrotate on the node host). However you can use `kubectl logs --since-time` and fill in the time of your last get. If you're trying to build something to iteratively process logs automatically, probably use Fluentd to load them into some kind of database (Kafka is common for this).

Comment: Well, you can configure the docker daemon to rotate the logs more often. You could as well just delete the docker JSON log files but I would really not do this. Btw. `--since` might also be interesting because you can specify the amount of time since the last log message.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think there is any way to affect that from Kubernetes. If you want low-level, sure you can SSH in an `rm` the log file :) But also don't do that, I think the question implies an impending misuse of `kubectl logs`.

Comment: Plus one for "_an impending misuse of..._" - usually followed by whatever I'm currently working on

Answer (score 10):

Found a couple of other useful log limit options.
This it to limit by seconds, minutes, or hours:

```
kubectl logs podname-xxxxxxxx-xxxx --since 10s
kubectl logs podname-xxxxxxxx-xxxx --since 5m
kubectl logs podname-xxxxxxxx-xxxx --since 1h
```

And this for a number of lines:

```
kubectl logs podname-xxxxxxxx-xxxx --tail=5
kubectl logs podname-xxxxxxxx-xxxx --tail=-1
```